# How to get most recent database entry and compare it to a textfield

Tags: c#, asp.net

having an ongoing problem with my project that I'm working on. Fairly new to C# and ASP.Net.

I'm currently trying to get an entry from a textfield and compare it to the last entry in my database. For my business rule, the Reading must not be higher than the *Previous Years* reading. I will have multiple Readings from different machines.

meterReading is the instance of my class MeterReading

This is currently what I have:

```
var checkMeterReading = (from p in db.MeterReading
                                     where (p.Reading < meterReading.Reading)
                                     select p);


   if (checkMeterReading.Count() > 0)
                        {

                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty())
                            {
                                //saves into DB
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            TempData["Error"] = "Meter Reading must be higher than last actual";
                        }
```

Don't know if I'm doing anything stupid or not. Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You're currently checking whether **any** reading in the database is less than the current reading; that's clearly not right, as you could have stored readings of `200, 5000, 12005` and be testing against `9000`. There are 2 readings less than 9000, so your code would allow you to insert the `9000` at the end. What you want to check is that *all* the readings are less, or equivalently: that *no* reading is higher:

```
var higherExists = db.MeterReading.Any(p => p.Reading > newReading);
if(higherExists) {
    // danger!
} else {
    // do the insert... as long as you're dealing with race conditions :)
}
```

Note that a better approach IMO would be to compare using *time*, since errors and meter replacements mean that the readings are not *necessarily* monotonic. Then you'd do something like:

```
var lastRow = db.MeterReading.OrderByDescending(p => p.ReadingDate).FirstOrDefault();
if(lastRow == null || lastRow.Reading < newReading) {
    // fine
} else {
    // danger
}
```

Note that your current code only supports one customer and meter. You probably also need to filter the table by those.